# Checking characters in a string array aren't duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, string

So the idea is for a given set of strings in an array, I want to combine them to create one string.

for example:

```
 array[0] = "abcde";
 array[1] = "bcfgp";
 array[2] = "fbcns";
 array[3] = "fbdrq";
```

I want to join them thus getting the first of each letter from the array.
Which I done fine with this code:

```
        String[] array = new String[4];
        array[0] = "abcde";
        array[1] = "bcfgp";
        array[2] = "fbcns";
        array[3] = "fbdrq";

        int wordLength = array[0].length();

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        // check through letter in each word
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            char[] charArray = new char[wordLength];
            // checks each word in the array
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                char ch = array[j].charAt(i);
                b.append(ch);
            }
        }
```

So this code creates the string **"abffbcbbcfcddgnrepsq"** which is fine.

What I would like is to remove duplicates at a position of i. so for the example used:

```
           i=01234
 array[0] = "abcde";
 array[1] = "bcfgp";
 array[2] = "fbcns";
 array[3] = "fbdrq";
```

so you can see that when i=0, there is a duplicate of `f` so rather than adding two f's to the string, how would I add just one?

i=1 There are 3 b's so i'd only add one to the string and the c

i=2 Only add 1 c to the string and the d and d..

you get the picture, the end output would be:

**"abfbccfddgnrepsq"**

Comment: are all the strings in `array` of length `i`?

Comment: They are indeed @trashr0x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Set` can be used to identify the duplicate as follow:

```
   StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

   // check through letter in each word
   Set<Character>st = new HashSet<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {

       st.clear();
       char[] charArray = new char[wordLength];
       // checks each word in the array

       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
           char ch = array[j].charAt(i);
           if(st.add(ch))  
           b.append(ch);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Beautiful, would it not just be easier to create the set after the first for loop? would not be more work? thank you though

Comment: @user3667111, yes may be it would, it's just your preference. Both are work's  correctly.